# XMLRequest not working to retrieve data and fill up data table

Tags: html, sql, asp.net, datatable

So what I'm trying to do is get data from a stored procedure and put it into a table on my website. When I call the API functions from my JS file (using XML REQUEST), the if statement never runs, and I never get a result back. Im not too sure where my error is because I don't get any error message, I just get no data returned into my table.

Function that calls to API from JS file

```
 function getStudentTopicQuizResult()
    {
        console.log("step 1");
        
    
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('POST', 'https://localhost:44303/api/JSON/getStudentTopicQuizResult', true);
        req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        
        req.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
            if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) 
            {
                var result = req.response;
                console.log("step 2");
            }
        }
        
        
        return false;
    }
```

ASP.NET API Functions

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public object getStudentTopicQuizResult()
        {
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            string sql = "getStudentTopicQuizResult";
            var json = ExecuteSPGetStudentTopicQuizResult(sql);

            response.Content = new StringContent(json);
            return response;
        }

 private static string ExecuteSPGetStudentTopicQuizResult(string queryString)
        {
            string json = "";
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbconn"].ToString();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                // 1.  create a command object identifying the stored procedure
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn);

                // 2. set the command object so it knows to execute a stored procedure
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                // execute the command
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    // iterate through results, printing each to console
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        json += "{\"name\":\"" + (string)rdr[0].ToString() + " " + (string)rdr[1].ToString() + "\",\"";
                        json += "\"topic\":\"" + (string)rdr[2].ToString() + "\",\"";
                        json += "\"score\":\"" + (string)rdr[5].ToString() + "\",\"";
                        json += "\"ids\":\"" + (string)rdr[3].ToString() + "|" + (string)rdr[4].ToString() + "\"\"},";
                        Console.WriteLine(json);
                    }
                }

                return json;
            }
        }
```

SQL stored procedure code

```
USE [Capstone]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[getStudentTopicQuizResult]    Script Date: 3/29/2021 6:01:59 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[getStudentTopicQuizResult]
AS
BEGIN

select  FirstName, LastName, QuizName, [StudentQuizScore].StudentID, [StudentQuizScore].QuizID, QuizScore 
from [dbo].[StudentQuizScore]
inner join Student
on Student.StudentID = [StudentQuizScore].StudentID
inner join Quiz
on quiz.QuizID = [StudentQuizScore].QuizID


END
```

HTML code for website page with table (Script code at bottom)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="../assets/img/apple-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../assets/img/favicon.png">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <title id=tabtitle>
    Teacher Home 
  </title> <!-- dependent on student login -->
  <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no' name='viewport' />
  <!--     Fonts and icons     -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700,200" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- CSS Files -->
  <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="../assets/css/now-ui-kit.css?v=1.3.0" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- CSS Just for demo purpose, don't include it in your project -->
  <link href="../assets/demo/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
</head>

<body class="profile-page sidebar-collapse">
  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-primary fixed-top navbar-transparent " color-on-scroll="400">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navigation" data-nav-image="../assets/img/blurred-image-1.jpg">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="welcome-page.html">Welcome/Overview</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- End Navbar -->
  
    <div class="page-header clear-filter page-header-small" >
      <div class="page-header-image" data-parallax="true" style="background-image:url('../assets/img/capstone/space-bg.jpg');">
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <h1 id="pagetitle" class="title">Class's Future <!-- dependent on student login --></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown button
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
     </div>
    
    <div class="col-xl-10 ml-auto mr-auto text-center">
        <table class="display" id="example">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Student Name</th>
                    <th>Topic</th>
                    <th>Score</th>
                    <th>Quiz Response</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
    
    <footer class="footer">
      <div class=" container ">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="https://mhs.monroeps.org/" target="_blank">
                Masuk High School
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="https://classroom.google.com/h" target="_blank">
                Google Classroom
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="copyright" id="copyright">
          &copy;
          <script>
            document.getElementById('copyright').appendChild(document.createTextNode(new Date().getFullYear()))
          </script> Designed and coded by Mike Aiello</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  
  <!--   Core JS Files   -->
  <script src="../assets/js/core/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../assets/js/core/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../assets/js/core/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!--  Plugin for Switches, full documentation here: http://www.jque.re/plugins/version3/bootstrap.switch/ -->
  <script src="../assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
  <!--  Plugin for the Sliders, full documentation here: http://refreshless.com/nouislider/ -->
  <script src="../assets/js/plugins/nouislider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!--  Plugin for the DatePicker, full documentation here: https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker -->
  <script src="../assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!--  Google Maps Plugin    -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE"></script>
  <!-- Control Center for Now Ui Kit: parallax effects, scripts for the example pages etc -->
  <script src="../assets/js/now-ui-kit.js?v=1.3.0" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../assets/js/core/helperFunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</body>

<script>

        $(document).ready(function(){   
                //var userName = getCookie('myFutureUserName');
                var userName = localStorage.getItem('myFutureUserName');
                var userID = localStorage.getItem('myFutureUserID');
                
                const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
                const myParam = urlParams.get('dataKey');
                
                var responseObj = getStudentTopicQuizResult();
                /*var responseObj = [
                { "name":"A1", "topic": "A1", "score": "100", "ids": "1009|10" },
                { "name":"A2", "topic": "A1", "score": "100", "ids": "1009|1" }
                ];
                */

            $('#example').dataTable({
               "data": responseObj,
               "columns": [
                  { "data": "name" }, 
                  { "data": "topic" }, 
                  { "data": "score" }, 
                  
                  { 
                     "data": "ids",
                     "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
                        //if(type === 'display'){
                              data = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="openModal(\'' + data + '\')" >Show Quiz Response</button>';
                       //}
                        
                        return data;
                     }
                  } 
               ]
            });

            
            
        });
        
        function openModal(quizID) {
                alert(quizID);
                localStorage.setItem('quizResponseID', quizID);
                $("#myModal").modal();
            }
                
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tested the call to your API with something like Postman?  When you use the "readystatechange" event on your XMLHttpRequest object, your "if" statement will only trigger when the request is finished (ie. DONE) AND the returned status is 200.  You may well be getting a different status value returned (eg. 404, 500, etc.).  So Postman is a handy way to confirm that the API call is actually completing successfully.  Otherwise, temporarily amend your "if" statement to determine the status value you're getting - if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) { alert(this.status.toString()); }

Comment: Before you travel down this road? Are you sure you need to do this client side? Would not a data pull into a datatable and then assign that table to a gridview/list view not be a lot less code? If you worried about not having a page post-back to do this, then drop the grid inside of a update panel - you thus not need a full page post back and you going to wind up with quite much the same result with update-panel. Now to be fair, if you using some jQuery.UI "dialog" then going all ajax perhaps is a better road - but it not going to be a performance better - but just eliminating a page post back